# C language alphanumeric check for bad chars

Tags: c, char, clang, undefined-behavior

I have this C code fully working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

int isAlphaNum(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (!isalnum(str[i]))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char *user_string = "abcdedf0123456789ABCD";
    if (isAlphaNum(user_string)) {
        printf(" is valid \n");
    } else {
        printf(" is not valid \n");
    }
    printf(" \n end \n");
    return 0;
}
```

the following is copied from terminal:

but when I receive input via socket like this:

```
90a41ae8477a334ba609e06cujdikj#%&%$@$Dkdfsﾉ,ￜﾊ"]￘ﾓ {ﾭf
```

or

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒814
```

the program crashes
at this part:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if (!isalnum(str[i]))
```

I used the function by @chqrlie and works:
****edited****

```
int isAlphaNum(const char *str) {
    //this message is printed , then craches
    printf("pass isAlphaNum userinput = %s\n" , str);
    while (*str) {
        if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*str++))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

if (isAlphaNum(userinput)) {
    printf(" success ;) \n");
}
```

all ok now
thanks for the help

Comment: how does it crash ? any error output to provide ? :)

Comment: Your program doesn't seem to take any input. Can you share how you take the input and where the crash is?

Comment: It looks as though you have utf-8 chars (i.e. 0x80-0xFF). Sometimes [depending on implementation], the `ctype.h` functions have trouble with these values (e.g. they get _sign_ extended to _negative_ values). Try: `isalnum((unsigned char) str[i])`

Comment: The input you provided doesn't comply with the ASCII table, see how the function is defined here, https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-newlib/+/master/newlib/libc/ctype/isalnum.c

Comment: For me it works properly. You have have a double quote `"` in the string you want to use, if you are just hard-writing it in the code you need to put a backslash before it `\"` or it will close the string and the rest of the characters would generate an error.

Comment: Also, with utf-8, a single utf-8 "char" can be _multiple_ bytes for the given codepoint. You'll have to account for this by joining the multichars to a codepoint. Or, at least skip over any char that is 0x80 or above (e.g. `if (str[i] & 0x80)`. But, even if you decide to properly handle the codepoint, [AFAIK] `isalnum` is only suited to the range `0x00-0x7F`. You may need a utf-8 aware function and may have to use (e.g. `setlocale` et. al.)

Comment: hi all the string is coming from socket i read like: userinput = (char*)&buf[index];

Comment: @CraigEstey the code works when the double quote is escaped.

Comment: sometimes i receive like: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒8 this is copied from terminal

Comment: Because of posting limitations here, we can't see the exact _hex_ sequence. The browsers will try to interpret the codepoint. We'd need you to post the exact sequence as _hex_ in a code block here. So, have your program do (e.g.) `for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) printf(" %2.2X",str[i]); printf("\n");` and post the output here. Also, what _language_ is the remote site using?

Comment: once it gets to: for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) , it crashes. cant print printf(" %2.2X",str[i])

Comment: @AvenDesta As I mentioned, it can be implementation dependent. Some implementations do a range check to prevent out-of-bounds indexing into the array and others do not.

Comment: The `for` loop, by itself, _can't_ produce a segfault _if_ the `str` pointer is valid. But, the `isalnum` _can_. So, remove/replace the `isalnum` with the `printf`. Have you done the `unsigned char` cast yet?

Comment: It would improve the question to post the code that is crashing  , instead of posting working code and describing the crashing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in your code, but it is unlikely to cause the problem on GNU/linux systems, but might on other ones: `isalnum(str[i])` has undefined behavior if `str[i]` has a negative value, which is possible if the string contains 8-bit bytes and the `char` type is signed by default. `isalnum()` should only be passed values of the type `unsigned char` or the special negative value `EOF`.

The function should be written this way:

```
#include <ctype.h> 

int isAlphaNum(const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*str++))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Your remark about *receiving input via socket* prompts me to suspect that you are not null terminating the string received via a socket. This could cause `isAlphaNum()` to read beyond the end of the array and cause a segmentation fault if there is no null byte until the end of the memory mapped area (which used to be called a *segment* in ancient Multics systems).

Comment: thanks for this fix, still crashes at this: isalnum, with correct and not correct chars - once the programs comes to isalnum() it crashes for both cases. i just checked it. i am calling #include <ctype.h>  in main, but i see it's quite weird

Comment: maybe the compile not adding: ctype.h?

Comment: You have posted code fragments, this does not help. Please post a complete program, trying to remove parts that do not cause a problem but keeping it compilable and producing the problem.

Comment: in fact it works, the error was after this code. thanks alot :)